# Override geolocation with static one in Opera 10.63

Tags: opera, privacy, geolocation

Opera now has the ability to provide my [geolocation to websites](http://www.opera.com/portal/geo/) (if I agree to share it with the website). However, for my desktop, I'd like opera not to consult Google / WIFI points / GeoIP services whatsoever. The computer won't travel until I move house, and I'd like more control over exactly where I'm placed with what accuracy (actually: they may know my location up to city level, so I'd very much like to drop a marker in the center of my hometown & claim that as residence rather then a more precise location). I tried setting the data provider to a local file, filled with the data according to the [google api](http://code.google.com/p/gears/wiki/GeolocationAPI)

```
{
  "location": {
    "latitude": 51.0,
    "longitude": -0.1,
    "altitude": 30.1,
    "accuracy": 1200.1,
    "altitude_accuracy": 10.1,
    "address": {
      "street_number": "100",
      "street": "Amphibian Walkway",
      "postal_code": "94043",
      "city": "Mountain View",
      "county": "Mountain View County",
      "region": "California",
      "country": "United States of America",
      "country_code": "US"
    }
  }
}
```

However, this does not work. Running a local webserver and pointing `Location Provider URL` in `opera:config` to http://localhost/location.json does work, but I'd rather not be forced to constantly run a webserver when all I want to provide is a static location. Are there any workarounds for this to enter a static location in Opera, or let it it grok a local file instead of an url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Added it to the [desktop wish list](http://my.opera.com/community/forums/topic.dml?id=765652&t=1286908020&page=1#comment7332162), and was informed that this Unite application, [Geolocation Provider](http://unite.opera.com/application/701/) would work.

> This Geolocation Provider allows to customize longitude/latitude, accuracy, altitude, and altitude accuracy. It also allows saying which information are provided. It not only alows for faster usage of API (not network requests needed), it also helps privacy by control of what informations are returned to Opera and then to web application. This application also make that on Geolocation requests, Google IS NOT accesses in any way (This Geolocation Provider replaces Google's one, in Opera's config)

Not a fan of Unite, but it solves the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simply publish a static file anywhere in the web, filled with the desired response, and use the respective file address as the geolocation provider?

Comment: Because if I wanted to do that, I'd go the already set local webserver route, and why should I store my location on the wild wild web, if it just needs 2 lat/lon floats? I'm just thoroughly disappointed a local file doesn't work, which would only be my second preference, the first naturally just inputting it in `opera:config`

Comment: As you said "but I'd rather not be forced to constantly run a webserver", I suggested put it directly on the web, as there are many paid and free places that you can do it. Even I would prefer to simply input the two coords directly on Opera, I was just being practical and proposing a solution that works right now.

Comment: My apologies, I wasn't really clear on that, and I do appreciate your answer. However, I'd rather not have it on _any_ webserver. Putting it somewhere is no problem at all, as I even own a couple of servers, but I'd rather not abuse on of those for serving one single file for an app that doesn't get the file protocol ;)